# Construct the polygon

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Given N number of Pipes of length L1 , L2 ,L3 , …... LN. Using these pipes,which can only be joined end to end (such that they can move freely in a 2-D plane only about the pivot/point of intersection) , I need to construct any polygon having the maximum number of edges (pipes representing the edges).

I need to find maximum number of pipes which can be used to construct the polygon.

Also tell if in Case, if it's impossible to construct a polygon using the pipes.

Example : 
If N=4 and lengths be [2,2,3,3] then here answer is 4 as one of the possible polygon is a 3 sided polygon(triangle) with edges 2,2,3. Another possible polygon is a 4 sided polygon(rectangle) with edges 2,2,3,3. Since 4 > 3 , hence, we get a polygon with maximum of 4 edges.

But if N=3 and lengths be [1,2,3] then here answer is that its not possible to make polygon here.

Answer (score 1):

First assume the lengths are in order $L_1\leq L_2\leq\dots\leq L_N$.

1. If $N<3$, you can't make a polygon (the answer is 0) because you can't even make a triangle.
2. If $\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}L_i> L_N$, then all the pipes can be used
   to make a triangle (the answer is $N$).
3. If $\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}L_i\leq L_N$, then the $L_N$ pipe can't be used because all the other pipes can't reach from one end of it to the other. Throw the $L_N$ pipe out of your set and return to step 1 (using $N-1$ as $N$ since you now have fewer pipes).

Eventually, this process will stop on step 1 or step 2 and you'll have your answer.